# Structuring Python OOP Code and Modules

Tags: python, module, package

```
packageName\
    __init__.py
    src\
        __init__.py
        someFile.py
        classes\
            __init__.py
            engine1.py
            engine2.py
            engine.py
    tests\
        __init__.py
        myTests.py
    temp\
```

I'm working on OOP with Python, and I have a few questions.

I understand that `__init__.py` defines the folder as a module, but what I do not understand is how this benefits me.

How would I run `myTests.py` if it needs to import a class from the `packageName/src/classes` folder?

```
$  python packageName/tests/myTests.py
```

The above call is how I guess I'd intend to run my tests. If the structure is the case, how can I import the classes?

```
from ..src.classes.engine1 import *
```

Comment: I highly recommend you read [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging 1.0 - Lay Out Your Project](http://guide.python-distribute.org/quickstart.html#lay-out-your-project). If you structure your project as a proper package and install it, you will be able to use an absolute import from anywhere on the system (example: `from src.classes.engine1 import something`). Additionally, I _highly_ recommend you avoid `import *` statements... they can pollute your module's namespace and cause all sorts of unusual problems.

Comment: Adding an `__init__.py` file to a folder makes it a _package_ of other modules (and/or sub-packages), not a module itself.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mike mentioned, The Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging would be a great place to start.

Now, as far as your tests go: for various Reasons, you can't just run `python packageName/tests/myTests.py` (specifically, Python will get confused about the package layout — when you run a file with `python foo.py`, it's expected to be outside a package, so the `from ..src …` line will fail with `Attempted relative import in non-package`).

Instead, you need to start your tests from *outside* the package… Either using a test runner like [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [unittest2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2), or writing a simple script in the top level directory (ie, above `packageName/`):

```
$ ls
packageName/ run_tests
$ cat run_tests.py
from packageName.tests.myTests import main
main()
```

Then put a `main()` function in `myTests()`.

However, using a test runner is much simpler. If you've [written your tests correctly](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html), you can run them with:

```
$ ls
packageName/
$ nosetests
..................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 34 tests in 1.440s

OK
```